# OpenCV Random Decision Forest: How to get posterior probability

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I did research on multiple websites, but I couldn't find any solution. 
Here's the problem:

I am implementing a pixel-wise classification using **RTrees** from OpenCV. I need the **posterior probability** for each class. I tried to get it via [cv::ml::StatModel::predict()](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/d7d/classcv_1_1ml_1_1StatModel.html#a1a7e49e1febd10392452727498771bc1), but the output matrix only contains the predicted value. Is there another way to get the posterior probability from RTrees?

PS: I'm still quite new to Machine Learning, so please forgive me my lack of knowledge ^^"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using [cv::ml::StatModel::predict](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/db/d7d/classcv_1_1ml_1_1StatModel.html#a1a7e49e1febd10392452727498771bc1), you could refer to the [cv::ml::RTrees::getVotes](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d0/d65/classcv_1_1ml_1_1RTrees.html#a46cd96dee4738c07899067344efe2956) member function. This way, in case of classification, you get the number of trees which voted for each class for given sample. By dividing these numbers of votes by the forest size you get an approximation of posterior probabilities.

The `getVotes` function should be called *instead of* `predict` like this:

```
cv::Mat samples = [one or multiple samples (their feature vectors)]
cv::Mat votes;
classifier.getVotes(sample, votes, 0);
// provide 0 here unless you would like to manipulate with RTrees flags
```

What you should be aware of is that the `votes` matrix is going to have one more row than the number of samples. In this first row there are your classes enumerated (in ascending order if I remember well from the OpenCV source code).

The answer is up to date as of the 3.4.1 version of OpenCV.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't updated that post, but I have already solved it, just the same way you described. Turns out this feature was introduced in the version released just a few months after my post.

Anyway, thank you very much for your help and your detailed explanation. I'm sure it will be very helpful to others as well :)